# Is this Serre's paper online?

Tags: reference-request

I would like to take a look at the paper by J-P. Serre, 
Modular forms of weight one and Galois representations. 
Is it online somewhere? (The paper was published in Frohlich "Algebraic Number Fields", but I did not find this book in my local liblrary.)

Comment: It probably also appears in Serre's Œuvres. Maybe those are in your local library?

Comment: In volume III of the Springer edition of collected papers, this lecture is reproduced from the typewritten original but also has several brief notes by Serre added at the end of the volume: one makes a proof more explicit, while two others provide updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electronic version of the paper is here: http://en.bookfi.org/book/465216